# Update row if column value is older than 1 hour

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql

I have this table in PostgreSQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pet (
_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
player_id int REFERENCES player(_id),
feed_time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
num_poop integer DEFAULT 0,
clean_time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
play_time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
health integer DEFAULT 100
);
```

I want to make separate update queries for `clean_time,` `play_time`, or `feed_time` and update each with the current timestamp only if the existing value is more than an hour in the past (according to the current time of the database).
If I am able to update, I want to add 20 to the current health value without exceeding 100.

I can do this by selecting from the database, doing all conditional logic in Javascript, and updating. But can I achieve this in a single `UPDATE` query to PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
UPDATE pet
SET    last_cleaned = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
     , health = LEAST(health + 20, 100)
WHERE  _id = 1
AND    last_cleaned < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '1 hour';
```

Besides being simpler and shorter, the filter on `last_cleaned` is also "sargable", i.e. can use an index.

Aside: it's "last_cleaned" in your answer, but "clean_time" in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The query below worked:

```
UPDATE pet
SET last_cleaned = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, health = LEAST(health+20, 100)
WHERE _id=1 AND
  CASE
    WHEN age(current_timestamp, last_cleaned) > interval '1 hour' THEN true
    ELSE false
  END;
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN age(current_timestamp, last_cleaned) > interval '1 hour' THEN true ELSE false END` is equivalent to `age(current_timestamp, last_cleaned) > interval '1 hour'`

Comment: The entire case construction is obsolete, just a plain AND is good enough

Comment: @Stefanov.sm it is not *equivalent* (in case of `null`) but may be safely used in this use caase;)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Fair enough, thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).